# HTML5 Audio scrub troubles

Tags: jquery, html

I think that this will be a fairly easy answer but I am unsure of why it works great in Chrome and FF but in Safari does not. It seams that the way the HTML5 audio player is designed that it blocks my function from firing. Again this is only in Safari. I wonder if there is a keyword that I am missing that Safari uses to distinguish there player scrub.

```
if(video != '') {
    $("#<?php echo $track_id ?>").mousehold(function(){
        video.currentTime = this.currentTime;
        video.pause();
    });
    $("#<?php echo $track_id ?>").mouseup(function(){
        video.currentTime = this.currentTime;
        video.pause();
    });
}
```

So what happens is when the user drags the audio scrub bar it also scrubs the video.

Thanks in advance all.

Comment: Are you really using $("#") as a selector?

Comment: Nevermind... I just fixed your code block and I see your real selector now.

Comment: Thank you ithcy, I was trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **mousehold** doesn't work in Safari... Try using **mousedown** instead?

Comment: Sorry that does not work either. Mouseup is what I am currently using as backup to focus the video to where it should be, but that only works if I click on the scrubbing area where the handle is not, but once the handle focus the mousehold does not work. I am not sure why mousehold would not work though? It is a plugin to add to the header of a file (<http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/>)

Comment: I was not sure about mousehold because it is not a valid DOM event; I would have read your link with great pleasure, but it's a dead one.

Comment: [link](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/) This one works now, sorry about that. I formatted it wrong.